# Gerund, present tense for the verb: бежáть?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have a question about present Gerund for the verb (бежáть). Does a gerund for present tense exist for this verb? Could (my guess) the present Gerund be: "бежaя" for бежáть?

Please correct if I am wrong.

I am using a site* that is usually reliable but for this verb Gerund is missing.

- starling.rinet.ru

http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morphque.cgi?flags=endnnnn

Comment: There is no such word in Russian. _Why you are creating a new account each time?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give an example of a sentence where you want to use it?

The form you are looking for is called деепричастие, and it is not really a gerund. A gerund is a verb form used as a noun. Деепричастие is a verb form used a adverb. According to Wikipedia, this form is called transgressive in English, but the Wiki article does not mention Russian. By the way, English doesn't have transgressives, and just uses participles instead.

Деепричастие can be perfective and imperfective, just like verbs. Perfective would be "бежав". As for the imperfective, I don't think it exists.

Comment: Thanks. I am in a hurry so  I awarded  you the Point since you were first to repond, Thanks. I highly appreciate your help. >Sleep well when it is time. :)

Answer (score 6):

There is no *formal* gerund in Russian, but English expressions can often be translated closely to original mood by using different parts of speech, e.g.:

**running away** (as in 'while running away, he didn't look back') - **убегая** (деепричастие)

**running away** (as in 'his running away was unexpected') - **бегство** (существительное)

**running** - **бег** (существительное)

to keep on **running** - продолжать **бежать/бег**

Verb-to-noun and adv. participle forms *mainly* exist with some prefixed versions of the verb (**у**бегая/**у**бегание, **из**бегая/**из**бежание/**из**бегание, **за**бегая/**за**бегание, etc.). The form you asked of doesn't exist (if there were such a word, it would sound like "бежа"), but still it can be translated as "**на бегу**".

**P.S.** There's also a related imperfective verb with no prefix: **бегать**, which can mean *to run around*, *to run continuously or from time to time*. This one gives the corresponding adverbial participle **бегая** with the sense '(while) **running around**'.